# Zend Framework 2, Event Manager, SharedManager, Form Init

Tags: zend-framework2

I have event  added to onBootstrap()

```
$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('\Application\Form\Presentation\Edit', 'init', function($e) {
        exit(print_r('<pre>') . var_dump($e));
    }, 1);
```

How I can run this event after call form method init ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solution,

In onBootstrap()

```
    $services = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $sharedEventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

    $sharedEventManager->attach('PresentationEdit','init', function($event) use ($services) {
        $form = $event->getTarget();
        $form->add(array(
            'type' => '\Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'name' => 'title2',
            'attributes' => array(
               'type'  => 'text',
               'class' => 'form-control',
                'autocomplete' => 'off',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'presentation.title',
            )
        ));
    }, 100);
```

In form:

```
use Zend\EventManager\EventManager;
```

In init method:

```
$event = new EventManager('PresentationEdit');
$event->trigger('init', $this);
```

It works, but is this the correct approach?

Comment: yes this is a correct way to do it, but i suggest you to use events on simple task like ``updatePost``, ``removePost`` or something else. don't flood your application with an event storm this reduces the overall readability of your application